# SQL CASE statement error with IN keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, case

I have a problem with this statement, I get an error near the keyword in:

```
CASE [table1.TransType] IN('Accounts Receivable','Customer Sales')THEN table1.Amt 
            ELSE
            CASE WHEN [table1.Billable] IN(0,8,28) THEN table1.Amt 
            CASE WHEN [table1.Billable] IN(1,2,3,21,22,23)THEN table1.RecAmt 
            CASE WHEN [table1.Billable] IN(9)THEN 0                 
            END
            AS NetBilling
```

Comment: You're missing a `WHEN` after your first `CASE`, and by the looks of things you are also missing an `END` after the `END` you have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your brackets may have been the problem. You were also missing a `WHEN` in the first case.

This should work:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN [table1].[TransType] IN ('Accounts Receivable','Customer Sales') THEN [table1].[Amt] 
  ELSE
    CASE
      WHEN [table1].[Billable] IN (0,8,28) THEN [Amt]
      WHEN [table1].[Billable] IN (1,2,3,21,22,23) THEN [table1].[RecAmt]
      WHEN [table1].[Billable] IN (9) THEN 0 END
END AS NetBilling
FROM [table1]
```

Comment: +1 i missed the bracket part first, there was just too many mistakes

Comment: @t-clausen.dk I had missed it as well. I had a minute to throw it into a fiddle and noticed it there.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 END missing: all CASE statements need a final END...so look after the first CASE !